# Moving the object on desired path using Accelerometer

Tags: iphone

I want to move the ball image on the desired path lets say a road with a "V" turn with the help of Accelerometer values.I have taken separate image for track with alpha non zero on track. Using alpha values I am calculating next point for the ball. This works fine for the part of the track parallel to X or Y axis.

But I am facing issues when moving the ball on slanted edges as shown below. Ball sometimes stuck up or gives jerks or moves out of the track.

```
------------------------------------------
 O                                       /
-------------------------------------   /
                                    /  /
                                   /  /
                                  /  /
                                 /  /
                                /  /
```

or (if image is not visible) please consider number seven image as track "7". Want to move the ball on track similar to like "7"

Comment: Please show some of your code.

Comment: This appears to be very similar to your earlier question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098785/object-motion-in-circular-using-accelerometer

Answer (score 1):

If you use an image, you should keep in mind that the resolution of those is finite. A slanted edge is not a straight line when magnified.

See this illustration:

```
          |
          |
        __|
       |
       |
      o|
     __|
    |
    |
```

If the 'o' is your ball, and it's moving down on the screen, it will get stuck on the pixel boundary. A better approach would be to vectorize or make a polygon of your ball path and calculate if the ball is still inside this polygon.

Answer (score 1):

I used **ChipMunck** for this and my problem is solved. Thanks for your answers.